# Datatype Inconsistency

Tags: python, dataframe, types, time-series

I have got a dataframe as in the following:

```
id, dt,                value
id1,2018-08-02 09:19:37, 2
id1,2018-08-02 09:19:47, 3
id1,2018-08-02 09:19:57, 6
......
id1,2018-08-03 04:49:27, 2
id1,2018-08-03 04:49:37, 4
id1,2018-08-03 04:49:47, 5
```

1) with `print(type(df))` it shows that it is a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

2) with  `print("df.dtypes =",df.dtypes)`, I obtain:

```
id                object
dt        datetime64[ns]
value              int32
```

3) Then, I do the following:

```
   df.value = df.value.astype(float)
   df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.dt)
   sub_df = df[["dt", "value"]]

   print("type(sub_df) ", type(sub_df))
  `print("sub_df.dtypes", sub_df.dtypes)`,
```

obtain

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

dt       datetime64[ns]
value           float64
dtype: object
```

4)  Then

```
df_grouped_by_day = df.groupby(sub_df.dt.dt.date).value.mean()
print("type(df_grouped_by_day) ",type(df_grouped_by_day))
print("df_grouped_by_day ", df_grouped_by_day.dtypes)
```

obtain

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

float64
```

5) Finally, I do

```
df_grouped_by_day["value"] = df_grouped_by_day["value"].astype(float) - df_grouped_by_day["value"].astype(float).shift(1)
```

Here I got the error `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Please, could you help where I am doing wrong? Many Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing due to how the data is stored in file, the `value` column is stored as string. You can try `timeseries["value"].astype(float)` and see if fixes the error.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the dataframe in question. This does not meet the requirement for a [mcve]

Comment: You say time series, but you also say float values, and your error mentions strings. What is the `.dtype` of your series?

Comment: Thanks. it is date:datetime64[ns] and value:float64 but dtype: object. is this the error?

Comment: @CarloAllocca If you can show us an example of your timeseries data, that will help us answer the question.

Comment: You say you have a series, so why are you indexing with `timeseries["value"]`? A series is just a single column, so there is no column indexing. It should just be `timeseries - timeseries.shift()` if I understand correctly.

Comment: @ Alexander Reynolds: Thanks for your reply. I did not solve my issue. It is still there.

Comment: @ G. Anderson: Thanks. I just added more clarifications and an sample of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the above issue by adding the following before differentiating:

```
new_df = df_grouped_by_day.to_frame()  
new_df["value"] = new_df["value"].astype(float) - new_df["value"].astype(float).shift(1)
```

Many Thanks to all.